# Python SMTP Gmail Limit

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, limit, smtplib

i am developing a program using python's smtplib which allows me to send emails to a group of people. i am aware that the gmail's policy regarding sending emails using SMTP is 500 emails per day, but is there a limit on how many instances i can use?

what i mean is for example i want to send 400 emails, can i open 4 instances of SMTP using my python script using the same email account and use each instance to send 100 emails?

i am using this simple script wherein i read the email addresses from a file

```
import smtplib


server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)

set_of_100_email_address = open('path','r')
for email in set_of_100_email_address:
    fromaddr = 'myemail@gmail.com'
    toaddrs  = email

    msg = 'message here'

    username = 'myemail@gmail.com'
    password = 'mypasswordhere'

    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
    
server.quit()
```

thank you

(P.S. i know that gmail already has this functionality and there are alot of programs/codes out there that i can use but i just want to practice coding it myself and i am curious on how things work)

Comment: I couldn't find that limit in their quotas page. They only mention the 500 limit. You should be able to run those processes in parallel and experiment to see at which point you get an error.

Comment: there is actually no mention of the number of instances.. i tested my code and it is ok for 3 instances and the code fails if i instantiate another instance after the third one.. but i am not sure whether this is the limit or my code is just faulty.

Comment: They probably use something like messages per second to cap it. By the way if you don't want to be launching different apps you could try using threads instead and just run one instance. It would give you more control in your tests.